# I'm looking to make a Nuke expression: I want the maximum value of an animation curve of another node

Tags: nuke

I want to feed a custom made NoOp node with a floating point slider with the maximum value of an animation curve from another node. What would be the right expression to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a built in method for that, but this Python expression will return the highest keyframe in an animation curve:

```
max((key.y for key in nuke.toNode('Blur1')['size'].animation(0).keys()))
```

where `Blur1` is the node and `size` is the knob.

Paste this into your expression editor, being sure to select the **Py** toggle.

---

This won't interpolate or extrapolate keys. It only iterates over every keyframe.

No guarantees on the speed of this either. It might bog down the node if you have a keyframe on every frame or something.

Comment: Would the name of the Knob be "intensitydata.r" If I wanted the maximum intensity of the red channel? Or how would I put this in python?

Comment: Actually it would just be `intensitydata` and the `.r` would be the `(0)` that comes after animation (0=r, 1=g, 2=b)